# Is it possible to say that problem A and problem B are equivalent, and B is concave?

Tags: optimization

Based on the assumption that $f(x)$, $g_1(x)$, and $g_2(x)$ are concave and positive, we get the following optimization problem:

**Problem A**

\begin{align}
\max_x&\quad f(x) \\\text { subject to }&\quad g_1(x)-g_2(x)\leq0 
\end{align}

But due to the constraint of this problem that is not concave, it rewrite as follow

**Problem B**

\begin{align}
\max_{x,\eta_1,\eta_2}&\quad f(x) \\\text { subject to }&\quad g_1(x)-\eta_1\leq0 \hspace{0.7cm}\\&\quad g_2(x)-\eta_2\leq0 \hspace{0.7cm}\\&\quad \eta_1-\eta_2\leq0 \hspace{0.7cm}\\&\quad -\eta_1\leq0 \hspace{0.7cm}\\&\quad -\eta_2\leq0
\end{align}

Is it equivalent to problem A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is not equivalent to A. Suppose $x$ is infeasible in A because $g_1(x) - g_2(x) = P > 0.$ In B, set $\eta_1 = g_1(x)$ and $\eta_2 = g_2(x) + P > g_2(x).$ Then $\eta_1 - \eta_2 = 0,$  so $x$ and $\eta$ satisfy the constraints of B and $x$ has magically become "feasible".

Even if you fix this, I'm not sure what you accomplish, since B again does not have a convex feasible region.

Answer (score 1):

If both $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x) $ are $\le$ than corresponding $\eta$s, don't think original constraint will be satisfied. Rather replace 2nd constraint with $\eta_2 \le g_2(x)$ and simply all $\eta$ s $\ge$ 0. You have indicated $\eta$s as non-negative but it's like holding one's nose by wrapping the arm around the head.

Comment: Thanks, my question has been edited to state that all functions are positive